# Adding string as a part of query in jdbcTemplate call in MySQL

Tags: mysql, jdbctemplate, querystringparameter

I have a query and a few parameters as follows,

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY ? LIMIT ? ";

//I am creating this 'sortString' on runtime based on some user inputs
String sortString = " column1 ASC, column 2 ASC "; 

int count =5;
```

I am calling the jdbcTemplate method as follows,

```
List<Map<String, Object>> rows = getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(query, sortString, count);
```

The query that is actually used by the jdbcTemplate is as follows,

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY ' column1 ASC, column 2 ASC ' LIMIT 5
```

Now, the ORDER BY clause does not works since the criteria is put up inside ' ' by jdbcTemplate. How can I add the string to the query without the jdbcTemplate adding the " ' " by default.

I want the query to be,

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY column1 ASC, column 2 ASC LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a prepared statement, when you generate a whole part of the query dynamically. The `?` in a prepared statement always stands for a value.
 //I am creating this 'sortString'

```
String sortString = " column1 ASC, column 2 ASC ";
```

String query = "SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER By " + sortString + " LIMIT ? ";